# Show that a minimisation problem is an LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am currently struggeling with the following exercise:

> Let
>
> $$(D_1x)_{ij} := \begin{cases} x_{i+1,j}-x_{i,j} &\text{ if } i<N \\ 0 &\text{ else } \end{cases} \text{ and } (D_2x)_{ij} := \begin{cases} x_{i,j+1}-x_{i,j} &\text{ if } j<M \\ 0 &\text{ else } \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that the minimisation problem
>
> $$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}} \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^M \ \big\lvert (D_1x)_{ij} \big\rvert + \big\lvert (D_2x)_{ij} \big\rvert$$
>
> $$\text{ with }\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^M a_{ij}^kx_{ij} = b_k \qquad \text{ for } k = 1,\ldots,K \text{ and } a_{ij}^j \in \{0,1\}$$
>
> is an LP and bring it in standard form $$\min_x c \cdot x \text{ with } Ax = b, x \ge 0$$

I think that to show that this is indeed an LP we should just find said standard form. My problem with this exercise is that $x$ is a matrix and I do not see how we could "transform" this matrix into a vector. Could you help me?

Comment: You can vectorize the matrix, but that's not the main issue. An LP means you are minimizing a linear function subject to a set of linear inequalities. The inequalities don't necessarily need to be linearly ordered but you can always take a set of inequality and order them however you want. The main issue here is that the *objective function isn't linear*. So the real goal here is to create an equivalent problem with a linear objective function.

Comment: Is the problem vectorizing the matrix? The variable $x$ is a collection of $NM$ scalar variables, so you can arrange them into a vector of length $NM$ in any order you find useful, for example row after row or column after column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $|(Dx)_{ij}|$ terms can be rewritten as a smooth linear function:
$\min |u|$
is equivalent to
$\min (p + n) s.t. u = p - n$ and $p, n \geq 0$
where $p$ and $n$ capture the positive and negative part of $u$, respectively. You just need to introduce these extra variables for every single absolute value in the original problem :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not quite see how this relates to my problem above. If I understand you correctly, you suggest to replace the absolute value functions via the standard procedure, but this alone is obviousl not sufficient since $x$ is a $\mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$ matrix here. Could you expand please?